# Лишний вывод при вызове функции

Tags: c++

В конце программы выводится количество столбцов, этого не должно происходить, но происходит, а почему я не совсем понимаю.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int n=4;
const int m=3;
int minstlb(int a[n][m], int n, int m)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
        int min = a[0][j];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
             if (a[i][j]<min)
                 min = a[i][j];
                 setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout << "Мин значение в " << j+1 << " столбце = " << min << endl;
    }
}
int main () {
const int n=4;
const int m=3;
int i,j;
int a[n][m];
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        cin>>a[i][j];
    }
}
cout<<minstlb(a,n,m);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: в программе выводятся минимальные элементы в каждом столбце. Покажите Ваш вывод и как он должен выглядеть

Comment: @KoVadim 1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
Мин значение в 1 столбце = 1
Мин значение в 2 столбце = 2
Мин значение в 3 столбце = 3
3
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 5.973 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: видите, после мин значения в последнем столбце, пишется ещё одно число, которого не должно быть

Comment: Вы его сами и выводите вот в этой строке `cout<<minstlb(a,n,m);`

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, Ваша IDE этого не фиксирует, но у Вас есть функция `int minstlb(int a[n][m], int n, int m)`. `int` в её начале означает, что она должна возвращать значение типа `int`. То есть в нормальной ситуации Вы должны были бы сделать в данной функции `return` и вернуть тем самым какое-то значение. А т.к. Вы этого не делаете, предполагаю, что возвращается просто случайное значение, которое находится в памяти на том месте, где должно быть возвращаемое.

Итак, что нужно исправить:

1. Если Вы не возвращаете значение из функции, сделайте её `void`, то есть вместо `int minstlb(int a[n][m], int n, int m)` должно быть `void minstlb(int a[n][m], int n, int m)`.
2. Если Ваша функция выводит что-то на экран (а Ваша выводит, т.к. вызывает `cout`), то, чтобы она что-то вывела, не нужно делать вот так `cout<<minstlb(a,n,m);`. Эта операция как раз-таки и выводит на экран лишнее число, потому что эта операция выводит **возвращаемое значение** функции, а не то, что она печатает. Чтобы функция просто напечатала на экран то, что Вам нужно, достаточно сделать `minstlb(a,n,m);`. А `cout` вызовется уже внутри функции.

В итоге я бы переписал Вашу программу так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int n=4;
const int m=3;
void minstlb(int a[n][m], int n, int m)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
        int min = a[0][j];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
             if (a[i][j]<min)
                 min = a[i][j];
                 setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
        cout << "Мин значение в " << j+1 << " столбце = " << min << endl;
    }
}
int main () 
{
    const int n=4;
    const int m=3;
    int i,j;
    int a[n][m];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
    minstlb(a,n,m);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Не знаю, в чём Вы запускали свой код, но, например, Visual Studio 2015 у меня отказалась его запускать с ошибкой

> Ошибка    C4716   minstlb: должна возвращать значение

P.P.S. По Вашему вопросу видно, что Вы не вполне разбираетесь в механизме работы функций в C++. Советую почитать, например, [это](https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/3.1.php), или же ещё любой из сотен доступных источников по данной теме.

Comment: Спасибо большое, только недавно начал изучать функции и с++ в целом)